# How to convert string date to datetime format for graphing in python

Tags: python, string, datetime, matplotlib

quite jr to this coding thing (python specifically) and with all given info I somehow still cannot seem to fix my measly issue one million google and youtube searches later...

I am trying to plot data from forex market into a chart(matplotlib I guess? open to suggestions).
I have 40k some rows of this. that I downloaded from my broker

`30.06.2019 07:00:00.000,1.13760,1.13760,1.13760,1.13760,0`

date & time , open, high, low, close, volume
they're all in string form, and I am able to turn all of them except for date into float numbers.
if anyone could walk me through in laymen's terms how the hell I turn the gross date string in my data set into a plottable date time I would be forever grateful.

I have this so far

```
with open('NZDUSDtick.csv') as nztd:
    csvReader = csv.reader(nztd)
    for row in csvReader:
        time.append(row[0])
        ask.append(float(row[1]))
        bid.append(float(row[2]))
        askv.append(float(row[3]))
        bidv.append(float(row[4]))
```

Comment: How are you getting the data into a DataFrame?

Comment: what do you mean? im importing as a csv,
this is what I have so far :


with open('NZDUSDtick.csv') as nztd:
    csvReader = csv.reader(nztd)
    for row in csvReader:
        time.append(row[0])
        ask.append(float(row[1]))
        bid.append(float(row[2]))
        askv.append(float(row[3]))
        bidv.append(float(row[4]))

Comment: What are you appending to, lists? Why not just use Pandas, for example?

Comment: lol I don't know, just trying to ID the rows is why I appended, just following youtube tutorial. I just want to be able to plot the data in whatever the hell, and I haven't been successful in turning the date & time into something I can use to plot, idk if I need to do that with pandas? it just wont let me use the date as it appears in my csv... basically just need a usable variant of the date time and I want to make the open high low close into candlesticks. in my own little graph. through matploblib or pandas or anything im indifferent, but I need the string as a float datetime no?

Comment: Pandas has a few methods to simplify plotting straight from a DataFrame. I ask because if you were using `.read_csv()`, you could simply use the `parse_dates` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use datetime.datetime.strptime -

```
import datetime
string = '30.06.2019 07:00:00.000,1.13760,1.13760,1.13760,1.13760,0'.split(',')[0]
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

or more to the point if you already have the comma-separated fields,

```
times.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I would recommend not using `time` as the name of a variable since that will conflict with the time module which you may have imported.  That kind of thing can really be hard to chase down.

Comment: Thank you so much, saved my life (and my computers) used the second snippet worked perfect. Cheers ! problem 1 of 873094243 solved haha

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [datetime.fromisoformat()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat). Although the expected input is slightly different from your dataset, you can still convert it fairly easily. Assuming timezone UTC, it should look like this: `2019-06-30 07:00:00.000` (Year, then month, then day instead of the reverse and hyphen instead of periods for the date). The returned value should be a python datetime object which is comparable and therefore plottable.

You can also convert it to a [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) using [datetime.timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp). A unix timestamp is very simply the number of seconds since the UNIX Epoch (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970). This is especially helpful because time and date can be unpredictable (e.g. timezones, irregular month lengths, leap years, leap seconds etc.).

edit:
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59402295/4526052) is a much better way to convert the date&time string to a datetime object. I recommend you use that instead of datetime.fromisoformat()